Can you adjust flash settings on the camera with a manual flash?
I have had some Yongnuo flash gear for a while and it has been totally fine for what I need (manual flash, some simple off-camera triggering, etc.). I recently got a Canon R6 and on-camera flash with the YN560 IV seems to work fine. I just went to try to change to second curtain sync, but when I try to go to the Flash Function Settings menu I get "This menu cannot be displayed. Incompatible flash or flash's power is turned off." Since the flash's power is not turned off, can anyone confirm it's just not possible to change these types of settings with this flash?

You're correct: it's not possible.
If you flip the YN-560 IV over, and look at its foot, you'll see this:

It only has one signal pin on it, and a locking pin. So it can only receive one signal from any flash hotshoe, which is the one carried by the big center contact: sync (firing the flash).
This, btw, is an ISO standard for flash/camera communication, which is why the YN-560 IV is sold as being compatible with multiple brands of cameras.
But all other communication for things like camera menu settings, TTL, or HSS cannot happen between your camera hotshoe and the flash because there's no physical way for the signals to be communicated.
If you look at the foot of a TTL-capable flash, it will usually* have the same pattern of contacts/pins on the foot that the camera has on the hotshoe. Having all of those pins won't guarantee camera menu communication with the flash (a 580EX, for example, is too old to do that, while a 580EX II or can). But not having those additional contacts/pins pretty much guarantees you won't.
*Though with the Canon R system, sometimes that's a little more problematic as there are now three separate hotshoes. ‍♀️

I am complementing Inkista's answer.
Who controls the rear sync curtain is the camera, not the flash. The flash is triggered at that point with the signal sent from the camera.
For a lot of functions, you can use the YN560-TX controller. To control flash groups, power zoom, trigger mode, etc.


Untrue in the case of Canon (don't ask me why, but without TTL communication, 2nd curtain won't work).  True in the case of Olympus and probably other brands.
